# RabbitMQ ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ Cluster is not accepting new connections!
The number of sockets connected is low, the only message in Rabbitmq log is:

> ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded

What does that mean? How can I solve it?

Comment: This is a warning to indicate you queue is peaking out. http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/mnesia-is-overloaded-td17587.html

Comment: ^ That sounds like the answer.  Why a comment?

Comment: set  CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True, check this link http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-ignore-result

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase `dc_dump_limit`.  Based on docs:

> -mnesia **dc_dump_limit** Number. Controls how often **disc_copies** tables are dumped from memory. Tables are dumped when `filesize(Log) > (filesize(Tab)/Dc_dump_limit)`. Lower values reduce CPU overhead but increase disk space and startup times. **Default is 4**.

So starting Erlang with proper `-mnesia dc_dump_limit=X might help the situation to fix.

Comment: How do you set the Erlang parameters?

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Has nothing to do with number of open files etc. It is fully documented [here](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap7.html#log-file). Mostly, you can just ignore the warning but keep an eye on the amount of disc space used by the LOG files.

Comment: For example, use `application:set_env(mnesia, dump_log_write_threshold, 5000)` (defaults to 100) before Mnesia is started. I am not familiar with RabbitMQ, so I don't know which config files can be used to set the threshold. The warning has to do with `dump_log_write_threshold` and not with `dc_dump_limit`.

Answer (score 1):

This may occur in a bundle of circumstances, from the machine being suspended to the runtime scheduler choosing to first give Mnesia forms no opportunity to run and after that, a great deal of time (with the goal that heaps of occasions fire in an extremely concise timeframe).

On the off chance that you can, consider using Erlang 17.x. This isn't an indication of an issue generally.

See http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/10/how-to-eliminate-mnesia-overload-events/ for more detailed info.

Comment: That only tells you how to configure Mnesia, not RabbitMQ. Mnesia is a persistence layer for Erlang. RabbitMQ sets its own Mnesia settings, and it doesn't appear to have any way to configure it. That might help a RabbitMQ dev fix this, but it doesn't help us.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem as well and here is my solution:

The log file: rabbit@localhost.log is attached:

[image: opend]

That says the number of my open file that a process can use exceed the limit.

I tried run `ulimit -n` in my terminal to see in my OS, how many files that a process can use, and you want to increase this number by doing this command:

`sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1000000 1000000`

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -5):

In mac:
Remove /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/

sudo rm -r /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/

and unintsall rabbitmq

brew unintsall rabittmq

than install it

brew install rabbitmq

start rabbitmq:

rabbitmq-server

Comment: This is just delete all existent rabbitmq and reinstall over, you are not solving a problem, you are hidden it with a clean start.

Comment: This is like fixing a hole in your roof by moving to a new house.